# A locally compact subset of a compact space is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $Y$ be a locally compact subspace. Does it follow that $Y$ is closed in $X$?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space#Locally_compact_Hausdorff_spaces_that_are_not_compact): "All open or closed subsets of a locally compact Hausdorff space are locally compact in the subspace topology." Pick a non-closed, open example.

Comment: Note that a closed subset of a compact space would again be compact. The general fact: if $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff then $Y \subseteq X$ is locally compact in the subspace topology iff $Y$ is locally closed i.e. it can be written $Y=O \cap C$ where $C$ is closed and $O$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=(0,1)$ with the standard topology.